# Django Stale CSRF Token

Tags: django, authentication, csrf

I set up my django application to perform email confirmation when a user signs up using the code from this [tutorial](https://blog.hlab.tech/part-ii-how-to-sign-up-user-and-send-confirmation-email-in-django-2-1-and-python-3-6/). When I test it, I go to the sign up page, fill out the required fields, and submit. The page sends me to the login page. I go check my email and click the link provided to activate my account which creates a new tab. Then, I go to the other tab containing the login page (which we were redirected to previously) and enter the information to login.

Unfortunately, I am met with an invalid/missing csrf token page. After pressing back, and logging in again, it is successful! What is the problem here? And how do I solve it?

When I click the link in the activation email, is a new csrf token generated and the other tab that has the login page has the old csrf token which is causing the issue? How do I fix this?

**Edit 1 - Login Page Template**

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<p><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a></p>
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Reset Password</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you add csrf token to your template right ?

Comment: Yup. All my templates have the csrf token.

Comment: Can you please share the login template ?

Comment: I added it above.